# Java Jersey Rest Web service Client Code

Tags: java, date, jersey

I am writing a Java code which calls a Rest web service using Jersey. Here I want to set the date as query parameter. But I am getting Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException. I am not sure this is because of the date parameter. Can you please help me resolving this. This is my code:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Current Date Time : "
                    + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);
    System.out.println("Subtract one hour from current date : "
                    + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
    String dateconverted = dateFormat.toString();       
    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost/viewerportal/services/rest/vmds/programs");
    //String s = webResource.get(String.class);
    System.out.println("Got the web resource."+webResource);
    MultivaluedMap queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
    queryParams.add("availableDate", dateconverted);
       //queryParams.add("param2", "val2");
    String s = webResource.queryParams(queryParams).get(String.class);
    //System.out.println("Web resource string"+s);
    String response = webResource.get(String.class);
   System.out.println("Status ------->"+response);
```

and this is my exception:

```
Current Date Time : 2015-07-15T19:27:38Z
Subtract one hour from current date : 2015-07-15T18:27:38Z
Got the web resource.http://dpev827.innovate.ibm.com:8080/viewerportal  /services/rest/vmds/programs
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: GET http://dpev827.innovate.ibm.com:8080/viewerportal/services/rest/vmds/programs?availableDate=java.text.SimpleDateFormat@fe8ba6fa returned a response status of 500 Internal Server Error
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:688)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.get(WebResource.java:193)
at com.ibm.cio.mediahub.PushToW3Search.main(PushToW3Search.java:89)
```

Comment: Can you check the logs on server, they will have the actual error

Comment: I don't have access to server logs.